# Gradle: Error running 'Debug Elasticsearch': Unable to open debugger port java.io.IOException "handshake failed - unrecognized message from target VM"

Tags: java, elasticsearch, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to figure out how Elasticsearch processes its requests and run it in IntelliJ. According to the Contribution Documentation on [Gitlab](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) there doesn't seem to be any specific setting for IntelliJ to be used.

The default debug configuration is as follows:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=innb01811-linux.v2c2.at:5005,suspend=y,onthrow=<FQ exception class name>,onuncaught=<y/n>
```

Which is fine until I send a default-request from the command line:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5005
```

In that moment everything fails:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
JDWP-Handshake
```

And the IDE returns the error:

```
17:32   Error running 'Debug Elasticsearch': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - unrecognized message from target VM"
```

I have opened the port already (ufw allow 9200/tcp), tried with 80, 8080, 8081 and 9200.

I can't select the option "Attach to remote VM" - then the error

```
Error running 'Debug Elasticsearch': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused (Connection refused)"
```

will occur.

I am able to run the project with the default "gradle" setting:

```
=======================================
Elasticsearch Build Hamster says Hello!
  Gradle Version        : 6.6.1
  OS Info               : Linux 4.15.0-123-generic (amd64)
  JDK Version           : 11 (JDK)
  JAVA_HOME             : /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
  Random Testing Seed   : B1C1136A696158BD
  In FIPS 140 mode      : false
=======================================
```

Any idea what is still to be done or why everything crashes after posting a simple request? Are there any other Debug Settings to be chosen?

Frankly I don't know which kind of Server IntelliJ or Elasticsearch uses. Can this be an issue?

Comment: What is the full `java` command line used to start the process in debug mode with all the actual options (not the placeholders shown in the question)? Did you try a different port number? Do you run the process you want to debug on the same machine as the IDE?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - how to show the full `java` command line? Usually it's not printed in the terminal by the IDE. I tried several port numbers and noted them in the original post (80, 8080, 8081 and 9200). I only have one machine. I'm a little puzzled myself why IntelliJ considers this as "Remote Debug"

Comment: In the terminal you can use ps command with the proper options to list the processes with their full command lines, grep for `java`. What run/debug configuration type do you use in the IDE? How do you start Elasticsearch?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - I have started it outside the IDE by just using `./gradlew run`. Inside the IDE the very same

Comment: You can disable Gradle delegation: https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png. Click debug in the IDE. Can you debug it now?

Comment: When running it in non-debug mode I get the following error: `$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:9300
This is not an HTTP port`

Comment: Java debugger protocol has nothing to do with HTTP and CURL is not the right tool to test it. You can use command line `jdb` to test it. You need to use Debug mode if you want to use Java Debugger.